# Hazards of Keeping Freshwater Fish in a Container that was Used for Adipic Acid

Tags: acid-base, plastics

I have an Intermediate Bulk Container (IBC) which is a large 3' x 3'x 3' plastic cube. The label on the container described it as storing **Adipic Acid**.

Is it safe to use this container to grow plant life and harvest fish life for aquaponics? Or is there a possibility that this acid has leached into the plastic?

My quick research has shown that adipic acid is a mild skin irritant.

Comment: If you clean it out well with soap and water, the fact that it was used to store adipic acid shouldn't matter. Not knowing the grade of the reagent (i.e. the impurities, may be some less water-soluble ones) or even what plastic the container is made of might be a bigger risk here.

Comment: Would it help if I provided more information that was on the label? Are there perhaps some simple home tests that I could do to measure the pH of the water? Perhaps if I did a pH test on water I filled the container with, and then tested the pH of the water again 1, 7, 21, and 35 days later?

Comment: You must monitor and adjust the pH of fish tanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Adipic acid occurs naturally in beets and sugarcane](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/foods-contain-adipic-acid-2051.html), common foods, so it is not likely to be very toxic to fish *if sufficiently diluted* by washing. As @DGS and @ghost state, normal cleaning of the container followed by adjusting the pH for the fish should be OK. If you need to use an electric in-tank heater, though, check that it is safe to use in a plastic container.